# Why lambda Transitions are not in Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines

Lambda Transition are not defined in Turing machines? What is the reason for that? 
Someone please explain me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [lambda transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_transition) would seem to be unrelated to turing machines...

Comment: In my final year course of "Theory of Computation" we learn in the following sequence: pumping lemma, finite automata (DFA, NFS), push down automata, Turing machine, decidable problem, NP, NP-complete. While "lambda transition" in NFA make things more simple and clean, linking up with the highly complicated Turing model and brings out this question is not really bad at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope my memory from 20 years ago still valid, please correct if any mistake!

Are you talking about the lambda transition in NFA? Lambda transition in NFA is mainly to simplify the complexity of FA only. You should also learn how to convert NFA to DFA s.t. it is deterministic and a "machine" is capable to "execute" it step by step to process its reflecting formal language.

Turing Machine is an abstract machine under Turing theory, and most of the nowadays computers' model (except quantum computers, which is still rare in our world). In my understanding Turing Machine is deterministic and executing over the tap to perform a "computation". There's no non-deterministic element inside.

Comment: Thank ken, Yeah I'm taking about the Lambda transitions in NFA. And yeah when i googled i found that Turing Machines are deterministic. Can you please explain a bit this sentence.
 "There's no non-deterministic element inside"
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I just want to state clear that everything must be deterministic for a Turing Machine. Once we have a lambda transition, that means we may have two or more valid and possible "next state" to go, which will make the TM failed to determine what it should do next.

Comment: This is false that turing machines can not be non-deterministic. In fact, the definition of the class NP (in the P vs NP problem) is defined by the class of problems that can be solved by a non deterministic turing machine in polynomial time...important topic.